# mod_rewrite - convert querystring to paths

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting, query-string

Im trying to rewrite a url that has a query string to its SEO friendly name

i.e.  consider

```
mysite.com/models?p1=v1&p2=v2&p3=v3&p4=v4&p5=v5&p6=v6
```

Id like it to rewrite to

```
mysite.com/models/v1/v2/v3/v4/v5/v6
```

or

```
mysite.com/models~v1~v2~v3~v4~v5~v6
```

whichever works better for SEO.  any suggestions

j

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^/models/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ models?p1=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3
```

Remember, that directory from "browser view" will be now /models/xx/xx/xx/ not gloal /.
So be sure that links to styles, images etc. are global, because after that rewrite, they can stop working.

You can also rewrite every link (excluding css,images,swf etc.) to 'models' and parse $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] in php (explode by "/" and fill parameters from array)